# Mutation component becomes out of sync with the store after updates

Tags: graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

This snippet appears long but is actually simple; it creates a node and renders its data and then updates the node and renders the updated data, but the data from the creation doesn't get updated, even though inspecting the store directly shows that the store for the `createFoo` query has been updated. I would like to understand how to ensure that components relying on data from the Apollo Client store are up to date, preferably automatically.

```js
const CREATE_FOO = gql`
  mutation {
    createFoo(data: {}) {
      id
      bar
    }
  }
`;

const UPDATE_FOO = gql`
  mutation($id: ID!) {
    updateFoo(where: { id: $id }, data: { bar: "baz" }) {
      id
      bar
    }
  }
`;

<Mutation mutation={CREATE_FOO}>
  {(createFoo, { data: createData }) => {
    if (createData) {
      return (
        <div>
          <p>{JSON.stringify(createData.createFoo)}</p>
          <Mutation
            mutation={UPDATE_FOO}
            variables={{ id: createData.createFoo.id }}
          >
            {(updateFoo, { data: updateData }) => {
              if (updateData) {
                return <p>{JSON.stringify(updateData.updateFoo)}</p>;
              }
              return (
                <button onClick={updateFoo} type="button">
                  updateFoo
                </button>
              );
            }}
          </Mutation>
        </div>
      );
    }
    return (
      <button onClick={createFoo} type="button">
        createFoo
      </button>
    );
  }}
</Mutation>
```

Data model:

```
type Foo {
  id: ID! @unique
  bar: String
}
```

Store data:

```json
{
  "ROOT_QUERY": {
    "userSidebarWidth": 200
  },
  "Foo:cjqd2cd41zi140a98ugrjpz2m": {
    "id": "cjqd2cd41zi140a98ugrjpz2m",
    "bar": "baz",
    "__typename": "Foo"
  },
  "ROOT_MUTATION": {
    "createFoo({\"data\":{}})": {
      "type": "id",
      "generated": false,
      "id": "Foo:cjqd2cd41zi140a98ugrjpz2m",
      "typename": "Foo"
    },
    "updateFoo({\"data\":{\"bar\":\"baz\"},\"where\":{\"id\":\"cjqd2cd41zi140a98ugrjpz2m\"}})": {
      "type": "id",
      "generated": false,
      "id": "Foo:cjqd2cd41zi140a98ugrjpz2m",
      "typename": "Foo"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you have a `Query` component like this:

```
const GET_FOO = gql`
  query SomeQuery {
    getFoo {
      id
      bar
    }
  }
`;

<Query query={GET_FOO}>
  {({ loading, error, data }) => (
    <SomeComponent/>
  )}
</Query>
```

When the component is mounted, Apollo fetches data from the server or the cache  (depending on whether the data is cached and what your fetch policy is). However, it also *subscribes* to changes in the cache. So if you fetched a `Foo` with an id of `1` and it's updated in the cache through another operation, the component will be notified of them and will update accordingly. Specifically, the `data` value passed to the render prop function will be changed to reflect the change in the cache.

A `Mutation` component has a render prop function signature similar to the `Query` component, including a `data` property. However, this property only reflects the data returned when the `mutate` function is called. While the results of the mutation are stored in the cache, the `data` exposed through the `Mutation` component is not the result of a subscription to the cache -- rather, it's just a convenient way to react to the results from the `mutate` call. The only time the `data` inside the `Mutation` component will potentially change is if the `mutate` function is called again.

If we modify your example and wrap the components in a `Query` component, we can show the data from the query inside your component and potentially ignore the `data` from either of the two `Mutation` components. Assuming the `Query` and the `Mutations` reference the same item in the cache, the data from the `Query` component will be updated any time one of the mutations resolves.